# Is there a way to madatorily ask facebook profiles for email using passport.js?

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, passport.js

I'm using passport-facebook for authentication in my node.js app, using the following strategy:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID     : '...',
    clientSecret : '...',
    callbackURL  : '/auth/facebook/callback',
    profileFields: ['id', 'emails', 'name', 'gender']
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
      console.log(profile.email);
...
```

This should be enough to get the id, emails, name and gender from the user's profile, but there's a way in which an user could
[untick the option to share his emails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aScqK.png) , in that case the value of the email attribute in the profile object returned by Graph API is 'undefined'.

I'd like to require that data to be shared with my app, is there a way to mandatorily ask Facebook profiles for emails using passport.js?

Comment: Not all users have an email. Just ask the user for their email if you really need it.

Comment: And there is no way to require a permission